# Styling for direct children

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

Given this example XAML:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Test">
        <Grid> <!-- outer grid that should receive the styles -->
            <Grid.RowDefinitions><!-- ... --></Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions><!-- ... --></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <!-- inner grid, should NOT receive the styles -->
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

How can I style all direct `Grid` children of the `TabItem` and no other `Grid`'s deeper in the hierarchy?

Here is what I tried (I put this in the the `App.xml`):

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

(I know that I can assign certain styles using `Style={StaticResource ...}` but than I would have to apply it to all `Grid`'s individually which seems lots of unnecessary code ...)

Comment: Other styling languages like CSS have these types of selectors and they are really helpful to have a clean and organized code.

Comment: WPF does not provide such a feature, and nobody is missing it.

Comment: @Clemens Given an application has dozens of forms and you want a uniform style in all of them. What would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: You already know that. If a default Style won't fit, set one explicitly. Beyond that, there are also DataTemplates and UserControls.

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer to actual answers ... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I style all direct `Grid` children of the `TabItem` and no other `Grid`'s deeper in the hierarchy?

By explicitly setting the `Style` property for all outer `Grid` elements one way or another.

You could for example create a custom `Grid` type that you apply the `Style` to:

```
public class OuterGrid : Grid { }
```

**XAML**:

```
<Style TargetType="local:OuterGrid">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
</Style>
...
<local:OuterGrid>
    <!-- outer grid that should receive the styles -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <!-- inner grid, should NOT receive the styles -->
        <TextBlock>inner</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</local:OuterGrid>
```

Or specify the default values of the custom `Grid` without using a `Style`:

```
public class OuterGrid : Grid
{
    public OuterGrid()
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(10);
    }
}
```

I am afraid there is no concept of CSS child selectors (`>`) in XAML.